# "rigidbody property has been deprecated" when trying to save ScriptableObject to JSON with NewtonSoft

Tags: unity, c#, savegame, json

I am using NewtonSoft Json to save data in my Unity game, but when I try to save something it get this error:

```
NotSupportedException: rigidbody property has been deprecated (wrapper dynamic-method) UnityEngine.GameObject.Getrigidbody(object)
```

I am not sure what to do here, since I'm not even using rigidbodies in any of my scripts currently and no other variable is called rigidbody, so I am assuming that it is something related to Unity's built-in scripts.

The error message also says there is a `GetRigidBody()` function on `GameObject`s, which is probably the deprecated part.

Also I am not saving any `GameObject`s / `MonoBehaviour`s directly, but I am saving a `ScriptableObject`, so maybe it is related to that?

Basically, I need something to save my `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're reaching for the NewtonSoft library in this case? I've just tested and Unity's built-in JsonUtility successfully converts ScriptableObjects to JSON and can populate a receiver ScriptableObject with data deserialized from JSON, without throwing any error like this.

Comment: I tried using the built-in JsonUtility, but it only saved the InstanceID and when I split it up into an extra class to save all values, it saved everything twice and with the wrong values for some reason (e. g. a bool declared as "false" is set to true in the save file without ever being set to true in code). After going through some forums I noticed that most people use NewtonSoft JSON instead of the built-in JsonUtility.

Comment: If you'd like help troubleshooting those issues with JsonUtility, I recommend posting a question about it, including a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. I'd bet once we can reproduce the problem, we'll be able to find a way to solve it. The built-in utility doesn't just fail randomly - it does what the code we write asks it to do - so you might just need a hand writing code that expresses what you want from it accurately.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I probably didn't ask the question correctly, the reason why I am not using the built-in JsonUtility is that it seems to just store the InstanceID when using lists of ScriptableObjects which is what I'm doing, I assumed that it generally isn't working with ScriptableObjects. So I am using NewtonSoft because on other forums it was said to also work with lists of ScriptableObjects. Unfortunately, because of the error, I haven't had the chance to actually see if it would work with lists.

Comment: You don't need to repeat yourself. "I failed to make it work with JsonUtility" is a good reason to post a question saying "How to fix this code that uses JsonUtility". If "Switch to NewtonSoft" is the answer to that question, someone will post a solution that uses it. But I bet we can either find a solution for you that works with JsonUtility, or your approach is more fundamentally flawed and you need a redesign to work with *either* serialization library. The only way for us to find out is if you share the code needed to reproduce a representative example of the problems you're encountering.

Comment: Created a new post with the saving code [new post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206626/problem-with-json-scriptableobject-saving-using-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: That looks like it should be an edit to this post instead, to avoid being closed as a duplicate.